# Realm search in multiple columns - Java Android

Tags: android, realm

I would like to search for all the records that are matching the combination of two columns in Realm. I would like to search `Users` based on the name.

```
class User extends RealmObject {
    ...
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    ...
}
```

User List : `John Doe, John Abraham, Joseph Kurvil`

Search query `ohn D`
expected results => `John Doe`

Search query `ohn`
expected results => `John Doe, John Abraham`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to split them by space and then search in both columns with OR

Comment: what if the first name is 'John C' and last name is 'Doe' and my search query is 'John C' the split by space will return 3 items

Comment: Well, another option is setting up that field `fullName` and searching in that

Answer (score 3):

While concatenated fields search isn't supported, you can split the search words for `firstName` and `lastName` and use `beginGroup` and `endGroup` to group necessary queries together to see if the whole words, e.g. `ohn D`, are contained. For example,

```
realm.where(User.class).where()
     .beginGroup()
         .contains("firstName", "ohn")
         .and()
         .beginsWith("lastName", "D")
     .endGroup()
     .findAll();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: what if the first name is 'John C' and last name is 'Doe' and my search query is 'John C' the split by space will return 3 items

Comment: What you can do in that case is to have another field called `String fullName` and query your string to see if a certain word such as `ohn D` is contained.